# CSS how to make an element fade in and then fade out?

Tags: css, css-transitions, fadein, fadeout

I can make an element with an opacity of zero fade in by changing its class to .elementToFadeInAndOut with the following css:

```
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

Is there a way I can make the element fade out after it fades in by editing css for this same class?

Comment: Use the css defined in this link to toggle fadeIn and fadeOut classes for the required element: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Use css [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

```
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fade 2s linear;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0 }
  50% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

here is a DEMO

```css
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class=elementToFadeInAndOut></div>
```

Reading: [Using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

You can clean the code by doing this:

```css
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class=elementToFadeInAndOut></div>
```

Comment: Adding *forwards* keeps the element hidden after the fade finishes its cycle. Awesome.

Comment: Kindly help on this one pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203327/css-animation-fadein-fadeout-2-images-continuously

Answer (score 29):

If you need a single fadeIn/Out without an explicit user action (like a mouseover/mouseout) you may use a CSS3 `animation`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdEpwW

```scss
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
  animation: fadeInOut 4s linear 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

By setting `animation-fill-mode: forwards` the animation will retain its last keyframe

By setting `animation-iteration-count: 1` the animation will run just once (change this value if you need to repeat the effect more than once)

Comment: Is the `-webkit-` still really required?

Comment: Not really in 2020, but in 2015 It was

Comment: How can I get this to repeat infinitely?

Comment: @KarimShaloh `animation: fadeinout 4s linear infinite;` vendor prefixes are no longer nedeed.

Answer (score 14):

I found this link to be useful: [css-tricks fade-in fade-out css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/toggle-visibility-when-hiding-elements/).

Here's a summary of the csstricks post:

CSS classes:

```
.m-fadeOut {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 300ms, opacity 300ms;
}
.m-fadeIn {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 300ms;
}
```

In React:

```
toggle(){
    if(true condition){
        this.setState({toggleClass: "m-fadeIn"});
    }else{
        this.setState({toggleClass: "m-fadeOut"});
    }
}

render(){
    return (<div className={this.state.toggleClass}>Element to be toggled</div>)
}
```

Comment: The different delay offset values for visibility are key here. Thanks

Comment: This should be the top answer, cause this makes the element actually hidden after it fades out.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a keyframes animation for the opacity attribute of your element:

```
<style> 
    p {
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 2s;
      }

    @keyframes example {
        from {opacity: 2;}
        to {opacity: 0;}
    }
</style>

<div>
    <p>[Element to fade]</p>
</div>
```

(You can also set the exact percentages of animations to make it fade in/out. For example, set 0% to 2 opacity, 50% to 0 opacity, and 100% to 2 opacity. A good source for this method is W3Schools @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation2 .)

Comment: This does not *fade* out.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, but I don't know if I would call the original post a *mistake*; by changing from `display` (which cannot be animated or transitioned) to `color` (which can be animated/transitioned) [and, just as critically, added a duration], you've *fundamentally changed* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@keyframes animationName {
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@-o-keyframes animationName{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animationName{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationName{
  0%   { opacity:0; }
  50%  { opacity:1; }
  100% { opacity:0; }
}   
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
   -webkit-animation: animationName 5s infinite;
   -moz-animation: animationName 5s infinite;
   -o-animation: animationName 5s infinite;
    animation: animationName 5s infinite;
}
```